# Receptacle Screw Connections

Tags: electrical, fire-hazard

[image]

I've replaced around 20 outlets and a few switches in my house over a few months. This is similar to how most of my wiring jobs look.

I've been reviewing my past work and am curious if it's safe for the copper to be touching the plastic (the black area) or not. So far, nothing has resulted from it but it is starting to worry me. Would that be considered safe or a fire hazard?

Comment: I don't see a problem with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plastic is *highly* insulated. Taking ABS as an example, the dielectric breakdown is in the range of 15kV/mm, meaning (in theory) that 10µm of ABS can separate 120VAC leads without risking conduction.

In short, it should not present a safety hazard. If you really feel it's necessary, you can bend that portion back up under the screw head, though.

Answer (score 2):

I find that the strip length of your wire looks a little long. I would recommend a somewhat shorter length as indicated here:

[image]

Comment: I agree. I try to keep it shorter than this. The photo was just an example.

Comment: Actually, many receptacles now come with a small "hook" (the area just below the white lines) to help band the wire around the screw if it is not hooked. So what's in the photo would be (and is) absolutely fine.